# Debate about Cardinality of Reals vs. Cardinality of $[0,2\pi)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My teacher claimed that the cardinality of the points on the unit circle (i.e. $[0,2\pi))$ was strictly greater than the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. I suspect he was mistaking the necessity of the existence of a bijection with the existence of a *continuous* bijection (which obviously wouldn't exist here). Am I right or am I missing something? The whole crux of his argument rested on a vague geometric argument and intuitively I could see why he'd think that but there is nothing intuitive about cardinals from what I've seen so far. Someone please put this to rest so I can finally sleep.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: Your teacher should be fired.

Comment: Just curious, what was that `vague geometric argument`?

Comment: Something that sort of looked like stereographic projection of the points on the circle onto a line. I think he just got a little confused.

Comment: If you didn't follow his argument in detail, are you positively sure that what he *really* meant was that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has strictly greater cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$ itself?

Comment: @dxiv Yes, I am quite sure of it. The main (wrong) idea he was trying to communicate is that there would be one extra point left over from the "end" (or beginning) of the circle that wouldn't have a point to match up to on the line. It isn't a completely ridiculous claim from the stand point of geometric intuition but obviously the intuition betrays us in this instance.

Comment: The construction you describe bodes pretty well with an argument against a *continuous* bijection between the circle (or half-closed intervals, in general) and the real line. Sorry, but at this point I am more inclined to ascribe this to some misunderstanding on your part, rather than sheer stupidity (or confusion) on teacher's.

Comment: @dxiv Fair enough but you might care to note that I already addressed that point in my question.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, I committed worse careless errors than that while I was teaching, so I don’t think it was a firing offense. The teacher should just be spanked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that is indeed what your teacher said, they are absolutely wrong. $[0, 2\pi)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality, as you correctly observe.

It is interesting to note that there is a continuous injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to the circle but not conversely. The idea of looking at a "continuous" version of cardinality is an interesting one, and one particular take on it (continuous preimages) leads to the [**Wadge hierarchy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadge_hierarchy), which is fantastically important in descriptive set theory. But, this is a completely different notion than cardinality.

Answer (score 6):

The cardinality of $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ equals the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ because $x \mapsto \tan x$ is a bijection.

Moreover, every two bounded open intervals $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ have the same cardinality because $f: (a, b) \rightarrow (c, d)$ given by $x \mapsto c+(d-c)\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ is a bijection. So $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0, 2\pi)$ have the same cardinality and clearly adding the point $0$ does not change the cardinality of $(0, 2\pi)$